# Speed up reading and opening files

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to read in multiple files in a loop but it appears my code reads the files each time which makes it slow. I have included a flag to read the files the first time only but it doesn't seem to work. How do I make the code faster?

```
program readfiles
use variables
use trilinear
implicit none
real:: coord(1448,27), inner_coord(1448,3),     interpolated_array(1448)        !
integer :: i, j, N, zeta, lam, k, l, m, row, inner_row, max_rows
Logical :: first_time = .True.
CHARACTER(len=100) :: FN 
type(string) :: array(3)
N=3                     !--arbitrary number of files 
array(1)%str = '2e8'
array(2)%str = '2e9'
array(3)%str = '3e9'

if(first_time) then
max_rows=1448
do row=1, max_rows
lam = 80
DO I=1,N
lam = lam + 60
zeta=20
do j=1,N
    zeta = zeta + 20
    do k=1,N
                    WRITE(FN,10)lam, zeta, (array(k)%str)!,k=1,N) 
                        OPEN(99,FILE=FN, action='read', status='old', position='rewind')!open the file to read
                        do inner_row=1,max_rows
                        read (99,*) (inner_coord(inner_row,l),l=1,3)!coorda, coordb, coordc
                            enddo

           coord(:,9*I+3*j+k-12)=inner_coord(:,3)
                    CLOSE(99)   !this ensures it closes d file it is reading from so a new one can b opened for reading 
    enddo
enddo
END DO                       
ENDDO
10 FORMAT('4e3_2048_',(I3.0),'_',(I2.2),'_',(A3),'.ksz_cl.txt') !length of this is decided by FN
first_time = .False.
endif
print *, first_time

interpolated_array = trilinear_mod(150.0,70.0,2000000000.0,coord)
open (unit=96, file='interpolated_array.txt')   !This bit flattens the array
do m = 1,max_rows
    write(96,'(30f16.13)') interpolated_array(m)    !'(27f13.10)'
enddo
 end program readfiles
```

Comment: The test on `first_time` is outside all loops in your program.  That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong but seems to me that you are doing your loop in inefficient way. You open file and move to the end of the file reading line by line and only use last read (1448 times, too much). Instead I would rid off outer loop (with row index) and move coord(:,9*I+3*j+k-12)=inner_coord(:,3) inside of the loop above and put under read.

Answer (score 0):

My fortran is rusty but i think it should look like:

```
    if(first_time) then
           OPEN(99,FILE=FN, action='read', status='old', position='rewind')                                     
           do inner_row=1,max_rows
               read (99,*) (inner_coord(inner_row,l),l=1,3)!coorda, coordb, coordc
               coord(:,9*I+3*j+k-12)=inner_coord(:,3)
               CLOSE(99)  
           enddo
          first_time=.false.
    enddo
```

Comment: I think that there is no need to check first_time. File will be open once since combination lam,zeta,array(k)%str ( assuming that array(k)%str is unique for given value of k) is unique. Close(99) must be outside of the inner_row loop. No need for first_time variable at all.